# Which libmagic did python-magic use?

Tags: python, linux, apt-get, libmagic

I'm using

`python-magic`

and I've installed it using

`sudo apt-get remove libmagic-dev`

In order to cite it properly, when i tried to find the authors online, i realized there are multiple `libmagic` libraries, e.g.

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic
- http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/3/libmagic
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic/

What is the source of the `libmagic-dev` found in the ubuntu apt-get repo?

Comment: Two of those three links are just to on-line man pages.  For example, `linux.die.net` does not contain any public source code at all, just a very extensive collection of browsable manual pages.  Unfortunately, the Sourceforge link seems to be to an unmaintained fork from 2000 tagged as "ALPHA".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`python-magic` depends on `libmagic1`

```
$ apt-cache show python-magic | grep ^Depend
Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python (<< 2.8), libmagic1 (= 5.11-2ubuntu4)
```

According to package information, `libmagic1` is from http://www.darwinsys.com/file/

```
$ apt-cache show libmagic1 | grep ^Homepage
Homepage: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
```

If you follow the link, you can find the link that contains source codes: ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/